# I want to Replace H3 Tag by H2 Tag Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to Replace H3 Tag by H2 Tag Using JavaScript.

Kindly help me!!

Thanks in advance,

```
<h3 id="replace_h3_tag_by_h2_tag">This is H3 Heading</h3>

<button type="button" onclick="changeHTMLTag()">I want to Replace H3 Tag by H2 Tag Using JavaScript</button>

<script>
    function changeHTMLTag()
    {
        //Help Me
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If it's just a styling issue, it's probably better (and much easier) to put a CSS class on the element, then switch the class on click.

Comment: Hi Friend, 

Thanks for your comment but I want to replace tag using JavaScript.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply change the outerHTML of the H3 tag like this:

```js
    function changeHTMLTag()
    {
        var el = document.querySelector('#replace_h3_tag_by_h2_tag');
        el.outerHTML = '<h2>' + el.innerHTML + '</h2>';
    }
```

```html
<h3 id="replace_h3_tag_by_h2_tag">This is H3 Heading</h3>

<button type="button" onclick="changeHTMLTag()">I want to Replace H3 Tag by H2 Tag Using JavaScript</button>
```

PS: Use a class or data-change-this instead of id to change more than one

```
<h3 data-change-this>Change me!</h3>
<h3 class="change-this">Change me!</h3>
```

and then use

```
document.querySelectorAll('[change-this]'); // for data-change-this
document.querySelectorAll('.change-this.'); // for class change-this
```

EDIT: snippet on how this works

```js
    function changeHTMLTag()
    {
        var els = document.querySelectorAll('[data-replace-h3]');
        for (var i = 0; i < els.length ; i++) {
            els[i].outerHTML = '<h2>' + els[i].innerHTML + '</h2>';
        }
    }
```

```html
<h3 data-replace-h3>This is H3 Heading</h3>
<h3 data-replace-h3>This is H3 Heading</h3>
<h3 data-replace-h3>This is H3 Heading</h3>

<button type="button" onclick="changeHTMLTag()">I want to Replace H3 Tag by H2 Tag Using JavaScript</button>
```

Comment: Hey dude, thank you so much for explaining in details with code practice. It really works!!!

Answer (score 0):

Old question, other answer, simply change the innerHTML of the H3 tag with a small regex, like this:

```
const el = document.querySelector('#replace_h3_tag_by_h2_tag');

function changeHTMLTag() {
    el.innerHTML.replace(/h1./g, 'h2');
}
```