# Change the H1 tag to H2 using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a way in Vanilla JavaScript to change the `<h1>` tag to `<h3>` tag for this HTML code:

```
<h1 class="price-heading ult-responsive cust-headformat" data-ultimate-target="#price-table-wrap-3686 .cust-headformat" data-responsive-json-new="{&quot;font-size&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;line-height&quot;:&quot;&quot;}" style="font-family:'Roboto';font-weight:bold;">Basic</h1>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322689/i-want-to-replace-h3-tag-by-h2-tag-using-javascript

Comment: Why was this closed as off-topic? The question is crystal clear and properly scoped.

Comment: If I vote to reopen I cannot vote to close as dupe

Comment: While I was asking for a simple change without adding an event listener like the dupe of above did, this question was closed?

Comment: @SilveroCeriano You never mentioned anything about an event listener in your question? Either way, I agree that it shouldn't be closed as off-topic. Unfortunately, [I'm in the minority](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/26978002).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
var dummy = document.createElement('h2');
dummy.innerHTML = el.innerHTML;
el.parentNode.replaceChild(dummy, el);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lzg47mek/